# Heroku: piggybacking safe

Tags: ssl, heroku, https

I'd like to create a tiny website for my client that needs to store some confidential information (but nothing top-secret).
I've created an heroku app for this. Since I need some SSL security, I'm thinking of piggybacking, using https://myapp.herokuapp.com. I don't care for the domain name, only security matters.
Is there any reason why this would be less secure than if I purchased a custom certificate ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None at all.  SSL is SSL, it just depends on what URL you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your website uses cookies, it is safer to host your app under a [public suffix](http://publicsuffix.org/), since then browsers will protect you from malicious supercookies. herokuapp.com is not a public suffix.